# Shouldn't this be transitive relation also?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

$ R = \{ (a,b) ∈\Bbb R^2 ; 1 + ab > 0 \} $

It is clearly reflexive and symmetrical but I feel that it is transitive also because the relation *R* can be stated as $ R = \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,2)...\}$ and as per the rules of transitive $ x,y ; y,z ; x,z = true $, and in the relation *R* it is true also, $ (0,1) $. Then why is not transitive? Are there some specific rules regarding $(0,0)$?

Comment: Clearly, we have $a R 0$ for all $a$. Transitivity would imply that $a R b$ for all $a$ and $b$. If there are negative numbers in the domain of $R$ then this is clearly false.

Comment: The domain should be $\Bbb R^2$ not just $R$, which is the relation itself.  Should it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not transitive consider $(-1, 1/2)$ and $(1/2,100)$.

Comment: oh! I was missing the fact that it is *real numbers*.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $a=0.1$, $b=2$, and $c=-3$.